# Не устанавливается изображение в imageView по intent из хранилища

Tags: java, android-studio, kotlin

Не устанавливается изображение в imageView по intent из хранилища. Ни краша, ничего, просто не устанавливается. Вроде как resultCode == -1.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

---

```
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/ivMyPic"
        android:visibility="visible"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />
```

---

```
val IMG_REQUEST = 1
lateinit var bitmap: Bitmap

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.add_event)

    val intent = Intent()
    intent.type = "image/*"
    intent.action = Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT
    startActivityForResult(intent, IMG_REQUEST)

override fun onActivityResult(requestCode: Int, resultCode: Int, data: Intent) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data)
    if (resultCode == IMG_REQUEST && requestCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {

        val path: Uri = data.data

        try {
            bitmap = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(contentResolver, path)
            ivMyPic.setImageBitmap(bitmap)
        } catch (e: Exception) {
            e.printStackTrace()
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: а в `onActivityResult` bitmap не нулёвый приходит? и какая версия андроид при запуске? на 6й и выше надо разрешения по другому запрашивать, через диалог разрешения

Comment: @zayn1991 версия от 5. Про 'permisson' я и забыл. Вроде с 5 по-другому запрашивается. Проверю -отпишу.

Comment: может и с 5, я точно не помню. bitmap на null тоже проверь

Comment: При возврате в вызывающую активити  через `setResult(RESULT_OK, intent);` вы указываете аргументом `RESULT_OK`, а приходит -1?

Comment: @pavlofff да, приходит -1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Нашел рабочий вариант, но с нюансами нужно еще разобраться.
Удалил проверку из `onActivityResult`, `resultCode` возвращался `-1`.

```
resultCode == IMG_REQUEST && requestCode == Activity.RESULT_OK
```

Добавил разрешение в runtime

```
val permission = arrayOf<String>(Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE, Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)
if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
   getImg()
}
```

Добавил проверку на null

```
bitmap?.let {ivMyPic.setImageBitmap(bitmap)}
```

Comment: `bitmap?.let {ivMyPic.setImageBitmap(it)}` чтобы было красиво.

Comment: @EugeneKrivenja да, так лучше :)